# flatten tuple into csv

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I have an array with names and ids, I have used python zip and dict functions

```
arr_zip = dict(zip(fnames,ids))
```

which gives me tuples like below:

```
[
  [
    [
      "f1",
      "1234"
    ],
    [
     "f2",
    "15234"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Now I want to flatten this tuple to write to a csv file with fnames in one column and ids in another column which should look like:

```
fnames  ids
f1     1234
f2     15234
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Could you give sample input for `fnames` and `ids`?  When I do `fnames = ['f1', 'f2']` and `ids = ['1234', '15234']`  I get a different output from your line.  `arr_zip` looks like `'f1': '1234', 'f2': '15234'}`.  And from there it would be easy to write to csv by iterating over `arr_zip.items()`

Comment: A `dict` cannot give you a list, there must be a mistake somewhere. It looks like `arr_zip[0][0]` is already the list you could give to `csv.writer`.

Comment: what does `arr_zip` actually look like when printed?

Comment: you are right, the output of arr_zip looks like - "f1":"1234","f2":"15234"     
           Here is my part of code that does zip: fnames = data['filename']
            ids = data['internalId']
            arr_zip = dict(zip(fnames,ids))
            
            self.output.write(arr_zip)                                                                   with open("file_attributes.csv", 'wt') as outputfile:
                writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=",")
                writer.writerow(arr_zip[0][0]) throws an error on the index

Comment: Thank you Padraic. I figured this out with some help!! I just had to do a for fnames, id in arr_zip(self.output.write(fname, id)